# ASP.NET RegEx Or

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am using the Regular Expression `^((IM[0-9]{8}(/)?)*|([0-9]{7}(/)?)*)$` as follows

```
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="ticket" 
    ErrorMessage="Maximo Ticket must be of the format IM99999999 or 9999999" 
    ValidationExpression="^((IM[0-9]{8}(/)?)*|([0-9]{7}(/)?)*)$">
    *
   </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This works if the user keeps to one side of the `|` but does not allow the user to use both types of expressions. For example the following work correctly

- IM12345678
- IM12345678/IM12345687
- 1234567
- 1234567/7654321

However I cannot combine expressions, which I would like to do. The following do NOT work correctly

- IM12345678/1234567
- 1234567/IM12345678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about moving the star outside the main group so: `^((IM[0-9]{8}(/)?)|([0-9]{7}(/)?))*$`